# View parent's onTouch method is only called when the child that's being touched is not clickable

Tags: android

I needed to intercept the touch events for a `DialogFragment`, so I overrode it's view's parent's `onInterceptTouchEvent` like so:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = new FrameLayout(GlobalState.getContext()){
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                mDecorView.onTouchEvent(ev);
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        };
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_number_dialog_layout,container);
        viewGroup.addView(view);
        return viewGroup;
    }
```

As you can see, I call `mDecorView.onTouchEvent` whenever the fragment is touched. However, the problem is, even though I know `interceptOnTouchEvent` is always called when the fragment's layout is touched -- placed a breakpoint on the `mDecorView.onTouchEvent` line -- `mDecorView`'s `OnTouchListener.onTouch` is only executed when the `TextView` is touched, but not when anything inside the `GridLayout` is; which are the only two direct children. I know this because I placed a breakpoint on the first line of code in my implementation of `onTouch`, and it's always called when the `TextView` is touched, but not when the `GridLayout` is.

Here is my fragment's layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="$"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_1_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_2_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_3_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_4_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_5_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="5"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_6_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_7_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_8_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_9_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="9"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/the_backspace_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_0_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_done_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="done"/>
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why `mDecorView`'s `OnTouchListener.onTouch` is not being called when the `GridLayout` is touched?

### Update:

Here is the body of `mDecorView`'s `OnTouchListener`'s `onTouch()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // offset because the view is translated during swipe
    motionEvent.offsetLocation(mTranslationX, 0);

    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag
            mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            if (mCallbacks.canDismiss(mToken)) {
                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
            float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
            float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean dismiss = false;
            boolean dismissRight = false;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                dismiss = true;
                dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                    && absVelocityY < absVelocityX
                    && absVelocityY < absVelocityX && mSwiping) {
                // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                dismiss = (velocityX < 0) == (deltaX < 0);
                dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
            }
            if (dismiss) {
                // dismiss
                mView.animate()
                        .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                performDismiss();
                            }
                        });
                return true;
            } else if (mSwiping) {
                // cancel
                mView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
            }
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mTranslationX = 0;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownY = 0;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            mView.animate()
                    .translationX(0)
                    .alpha(1)
                    .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                    .setListener(null);
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mTranslationX = 0;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownY = 0;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math.abs(deltaX) / 2) {
                mSwiping = true;
                mSwipingSlop = (deltaX > 0 ? mSlop : -mSlop);
                mView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                // Cancel listview's touch
                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex() <<
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                mView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                cancelEvent.recycle();
            }

            if (mSwiping) {
                mTranslationX = deltaX;
                mView.setTranslationX(deltaX - mSwipingSlop);
                // TODO: use an ease-out interpolator or such
                mView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                        1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as I was wrong-  read it as gridview not gridlayout.

Comment: @GabeSechan given the new information, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: My only thought is to take off "clickable=false".

Comment: @GabeSechan tried that after i posted the layout code. just updated it

Comment: Is onInterceptTouchEvent() ever called?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice always. read question.

Comment: Did you step into onTouchEvent()?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of mDecorView and onTouchEvent().

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i tried stepping into it both times -- after clicking the textview and after clicking inside the gridlayout. when i try to step into after clicking the textview, it steps in as it normally would. but when i try after clicking within the gridlayout, it not only doesn't step in, it doesn't bring me to the next line of execution. and if i keep pressing step over, eventually it "magically" gets back to return `super.onInterceptTouchEvent` the line after `mDecorView.onTouchEvent`

Comment: How many times do you press step over? How many lines are in onTouchEvent()? Have you tried adding log statements. Possibly the issue is with the debugged not your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the problem is, the `View` `mDecorView` is a view that i get from the `Dialog`'s `Window` variable. and `Window` is an abstract class, so the implementation that `Dialog` uses is called `PhoneWindow` but it's not packaged with the SDK, so it's possible the view that it gives me when i call `PhoneWindow.getDecorView` has some different implementation of `onTouchEvent` that i cannot see; but if `onTouchEvent` isn't overriden then it'd just be the default implementation in `View`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok, i added the log statements, and i know for a fact that `mDecorView`'s `OnTouchListener`'s `onTouch` method is not being called when i click within the `GridLayout`

Comment: You call a method named onTouchEvent() and implement one named onTouch(). Obviously, onTouchEvent() does not call onTouch() like you seem to assume.

Comment: Rather than trying to call an event callback method directly, I suggest creating a utility method that implements the shared functionality and is called from each callback.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i misspoke. what i meant to say is, it is `onTouch` that is always called by `OnTouchEvent` when the `TextView` is touched, so i know for a fact that `OnTouchEvent` calls `onTouch`. and what i've just found out is that it has to do with the buttons being clickable. i just set an `OnClickListener` on the `TextView` and afterwards `onTouch` was no longer being called, and i also stopped setting one of the button's `OnClickListener` and set its `android:clickable="false"` in xml and then when i touched it, `onTouch` was being called just like when i touched the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Callback methods are designed to be called by the event handling system, not by your own code. When events share functionality, it is best to put the common code in a method which can be called by any callback method. This is preferable to calling a callback directly yourself because you have more control. You know exactly when the method will execute and you can accept only parameters which are meaningful to the task at hand.

Comment: with your advice i was able to implement a solution, but i'd still like an answer to my question: why a view parent's `OnTouchListener`'s `onTouch` was only being called when the child view that was being clicked was not clickable

Comment: onTouch() was never called because you never did so. You called **onTouchEvent()** instead.

Comment: @shoe then I'm confused. What's the problem?

Comment: @shoe that is what I mean. The times onTouch() doesn't get called is because you call onTouch**Event**(). Why would you expect onTouch() to be called when you don't call it?

Comment: ...i've never called onTouch directly, only onTouchEvent. so it doesn't make sense to say "The times onTouch() doesn't get called is because you call onTouch**Event**()" because i always call onTouchEvent and onTouch still gets called. methods are capable of calling other methods.